# MVC: Is it possible to (and should I) make the controller reusable for different View's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view (view1) that contains 2 grids, each with its own collection (col1, col2). view1 implemets the IView1 Interface that contains the following methods:

```
LoadCol1(IEnumerable<SomeType> Col1)
LoadCol2(IEnumerable<SomeType> Col2)
```

There is also a controller that interacts with view1 through the IView1 interface, and calls `LoadCol1` and `LoadCol2` whenever.

So far so good, everything works, and i believe that this is a By-The-Book MVC implementation (please correct me if i'm wrong). But what if tomorrow i'll have another view (view2) that contains only the col1 grid? view2 cannot implement the IView1 interface, because it requires implementation of LoadCol2.

I can think of several solutions, but i'm asking for the best practice.

EDIT: What i'm actually asking is can (and should) I make the controller reusable for different View's.